# Google Chrome Extension: how can interact with original page script

Tags: dom, google-chrome-extension, virtual-machine, code-injection

Via my Google Chrome Extension I inject `mycode.js` in web page, say "www.abc.random".

The original page uses a script over a Dom element, say `#used-element`, with code similar to:

```
$('#used-element').unbind().bind('change',function(){ alert('You\'re welcome!');});
```

To trigger this event, in `mycode.js` (that is my extension's injected script) I use this:

```
setInterval(function(){
    $('#used-element').trigger('change');
}, 30000);
```

My problem is that the `change` event triggered via `mycode.js` doesn't fire the listening `change` in original page.

If in Web Developer Console I write `$('#used-element').trigger('change');` and press enter, then this event fire both `mycode.js` and `original page script`.

Someone can help me to force my injected events fire over original page script events?

Thanks.

Comment: Reading [https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#execution-environment](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#execution-environment) I learn that actually it's not possible realize my goal.

Comment: To partially solve this, In `mycode.js` I've imported dinamically all original pages script, so that they could be runned inside my script world. That's not optimal solution, so if someone knows a trick, it could be great!